# how to update parameter and pass to solve_ivp in Python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

In my ODE function I need to iteratively solve an equation for a parameter until convergence at each time step. I'd like to pass the latest parameter value to be used as the initial value for the next time step so when the function does the iterative update of the parameter it will take less time. But I can't figure out how to do that. The code structure of the ODE function is like this:

```py
    from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

    def run(t, y):
      if t==0:
        a = 1e-8
      nn = 0
      while nn<=100:
        nn = nn +1
        #update a until convergence
    return a*y
```

In some one language I can return the updated parameter to be used by the integrator, but I don't' see how that's possible with `solve_ivp`

Comment: To be more clear in what you want to achieve, as I have seen this before: You want to solve some implicit ODE like `y'=v, F(t,y,v)=0`. You already have some fixed-point iteration equivalent to this equation `v=g(t,y,v)` that converges reasonably fast. All that remains is to find a good initial guess for the fixed-point iteration, and you want to use the last value or a good extrapolated value for it?

Comment: Of course, if scipy.integrate had DAE solvers, I would recommend see the formulation `y'=v, 0=F(t,y,v)` as a semi-explicit index-1 differential-algebraic system of equations. Then the question of the implicit solutions and good initial points is addressed automatically/internally.

Comment: Exactly! The parameter satisfies a nonlinear algebraic equation. Its solution is sensitive to the initial guess so it's best to use the value from the present time step as the initial guess to start the nonlinear solver iteration for the next time step.

Comment: I see that point of using DAE. But I feel the more general point is if it is possible to let the ODE function return values other than the derivatives, and if the solver can use the returned values that are not derivatives. I have used R and Julia before which both allow some kind of callbacks to let the ODE function return values that are not limited to derivatives.

Comment: The more specialized situation you describe would be `y'=a*y, 0=F(t,y,a)` with the adapting parameter `a`? There can be multiple roots of `a`, but you want the curve for `a(t)` to be continuous. Which becomes problematic when the active root gets close to another root. Sometimes it helps to force the derivative of `a(t)` to be also continuous.

Comment: It is one thing to return some values to an observer function, it is a different thing to pass dynamic values back into the ODE function. The solver is usually a black-box, with quasi unpredictable evaluation points for the ODE function. Access to global variables can thus have strange effects. Events and actions are suitable mechanisms to implement such control mechanisms in some situations, but would be ill-suited here, even apart from the fact that scipy.integrate does not have a built-in action mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something in the following form:

```
class test:
    a = 1e-8
    def f(self, t, y):
        ## do iter on self.a
        return self.a*y
        
t = test()
# solve_ivp(t.f, .....)
```

This way you can always use the last value of `a`, since it is part of your instance of the `test` class. This is not exactly what you are asking for, since this will call the iteration each time `solve_ivp` evaluates `f`, which will be multiple times per timestep. However, I think this is the closest you can get, since `solve_ivp` does not appear to have a `callback` function to invoke after each timestep

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're after: do you want to obtain a solution for an ODE at a series of parameter values (i.e. for each value of the parameter you solve the full ODE) or you are changing the parameter *along* with the ODE iterations (IOW, you want inner or outer iterations).

If the former, then just do a for loop over the parameters. If the latter, it's likely easier and cleaner to use solver classes which implement specific solvers (DOPRI, Radau, RK, BDF etc), which solve_ivp delegates the work to. They offer a `step` method, which performs a single step. So that you can adjust you parameters, control convergence etc on a way that's most relevant to this particular case.

Comment: It's the latter I want. The parameters depend on the state. In practice I don't need to pass the parameter values to the next time step, since it can be solved iteratively at each time step. But that consumes time. So if I can pass the present value to the next time step, it will take fewer iterations to converge to a new parameter. So the key point if it is possible to let the ODE function return values other than the derivatives, and if the solver can use the returned values.