# Use solve_ivp with a forcing function whose values are user-specified

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I have checked the following two questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313305/how-to-update-parameter-and-pass-to-solve-ivp-in-python) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434975/implementing-a-forcing-function-for-use-in-scipys-solve-ivp-function). I believe #1 has a good idea of using solve_ivp for each time step individually, but it would be very slow and tedious. #2, unfortunately, has a slightly different goal since its forcing function is defined by t. In my case, it's user-defined. For example, if we have the ODE system:

```
\dot{x} = x + u
```

and  I want to integrate this from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1. But I have 10 values of the u at t=0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9. I want to pass these u values to the integrator so that it takes the first value during the first integration time step, the second value in the second time step, and so on. Right now, I cannot do so since the dydt function used in solve_ivp refers to a single time instant and doesn't accept the whole array. Is there any way to do this with solve_ivp or should I make my own solver by hand?

Comment: Is your `u` function piecewise constant, piecewise linear, polynomial, ...? Use the function table to construct the corresponding interpolation function using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, using the available options.

Comment: @LutzLehmann My u is constant over each integration step. So, in the above example, for the 10 values/time steps of integration, I would have 10 values of u. The first value would be used to start integrating, while the second value would be the value used after one full integration step is done and we found x at 0.1. So the second u value is used when integrating from 0.1 to 0.2. I don't think any interpolation should be required. Did that clarify my question?

Comment: This is called a zero-order hold and available as option in interp1d. Any method that transforms a discrete function table into a function over continuous time is interpolation, it need not be piecewise linear or polynomial.

Comment: What about having `u` as a dictionary? It would have 10 keys (e.g. 0, 0.1, 0.2, etc...), and each key points to the value of `u` during the interval `key + 0.1`. Then, within the function you give to `solve_ivp`, you simply write something like `u[int(t / 0.1) * 0.1]`. That should work.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, I was able to use the zero order hold to convert the data into a function and call it as a function of t in my ODE definition.